# Can't see pdf in UIWebView (the app is approved by Apple)

Tags: pdf, webview, ios6

One of my app's functions is to present PDF file (from app bundle) in a UIWebView.

On my iPhone it works fine, but I've got some reports that on other devices PDF file isn't presented.

What could be the problem? Could it have something to do with iOS version on those devices?

This is how I present the file inside the app:

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.fileName ofType:@".pdf"];
if (!pdfPath) {
    Helper* h = [[Helper alloc]init];
    pdfPath = [h filesinADocumentFolder:self.fileName];
}

self.pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
[self.webView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfUrl]];
[self.webView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.webView1 setOpaque:NO];
```

Comment: Why are you calling -[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType] and then converting to a URL when you could just call -[NSBundle URLForResource:withExtension] instead? I don't know if it will solve your issue, but it seems like it leaves less room for error.

Comment: I don't have a special reason, but it isn't really metter because on IOS6 it is working great